# OAuth 2.0 Client Identity for Mobile Native App and pure JS client

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, identityserver4, identityserver3

I was reseating OAuth docs and understand that https://auth0.com/docs/flows/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce is better than Authorization Code Flow, because it gives less possibility to get clients code and exchange it for access_token

Also I saw that there were cases in the internet when client secrets where reversed from big mobile applications like facebook or twitter

So for me it is still not clear how to get client identity implemented properly
e.g. if I use resource owner grant type I have client id and client secret stored in my app and this can be reverse engineered and anybody can build the same application as mine

if I use **Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange** I still don't have any secret inside my app. So it means that any developer can built his own app that will be mirror of my app.

So the question if there any wasy to implement client identity properly for mobile app and pure JS (browser) clients ?

**UPDATE**
there are 2 great options
1 - use redirect urls
2 - setup CORS

1 howerer I think it will not help if I will try to mimic bahaviour with back-end code. E.g. I don't really need to have access to web site to see that at some point it will give redirect in header and I just get the message and have this authorization code
2 the same for CORS in case for my mirror site I will do getting token from backend the server will not identify that client is not the original and that has rights to work with this client

Answer (score 1):

> So the question if there any ways to implement client identity properly for mobile app and pure JS (browser) clients ?

Per [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1), client authentication is mandatory for Authorization code flow. `redirection URI` is a suggested solution to help on client Authentication.
Here is options on IDS4 to help authenticate the client:

1. Using `RedirectUris` on client config to specify the allowed URIs to return tokens or authorization codes. [Ref](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/client.html?highlight=RedirectUris#basics)
2. using [CORS](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/cors.html?highlight=cors#cors). The browser's same-origin policy blocks reading a resource from a different origin. We can add our client to list of allowed cross-origin calls.

Code example:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "js",
    ClientName = "JavaScript Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    RequireClientSecret = false,
    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5003/callback.html" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5003/index.html" },
    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "https://localhost:5003" },
    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  AllowedCorsOrigins = { "https://localhost:5003" }, is exactely what I was looking for.

Comment: RedirectUris I am aware of this consept and was thinking that this is a solition for a long time. But then I realized that in order to get token you don't really need to owe the site so you can just check traffic and in the response in redirect url you just see the code. So this means that theoretically you can steak this without having rights to redirect url (somthing similar to what postman i doing)

Comment: as I understnad this consept will work event for mobile. but in this case you will have redirect to the browser and put login and passowrd there. Just wonder what is the best flow to use in case I have my own login screen inside mobile app and want to use it, And try not to store client secret somewhere in mobile is there a good approach to fix this ?

Comment: What you are say is called [code substitution attack](https://nat.sakimura.org/2016/01/25/cut-and-pasted-code-attack-in-oauth-2-0-rfc6749/). PKCE is a solution to mitigate it. In simple word having client authentication (clientId + Redirect URL + CORS) + PKCE makes it much harder to hack. As there is multiple checks and random generated values involved. The middleman should be sitting on user's machine and do the phishing to succeed.  Read more https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#interactive-clients

Comment: PKCE is he official recommendation for native applications (Ref: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8252#section-6)

Comment: Here is a ref for embedded login page using Auth0, it might help you a bit to figure out the implementation details https://auth0.com/docs/microsites/add-login/add-login-native-mobile-app#alternative-use-embedded-login

Comment: thanks a lot for very detailed answers will check links